# pdfbox - After LTV Certification Signature, PDF shows "Document has been Changed"

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature, x509certificate, certify

I am adding certifying signature using pdfbox. It is working fine but after adding LTV information, it is showing the message in acrobat that "Changes have been made to this document that are permitted by the certifying party". I am referring [this link](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/validation/AddValidationInformation.java) for adding LTV information.

How can I resolve this issue?

For certifying signature I am setting MDP permission as 2.

Comment: The message is correct, though, isn't it?